# Storing Multitouch points in an array

Tags: android

If I touch my device with my 5 finger tips, my application draws a circle around the touch points. Now, to recognize between my left and right hand I need the values of x,y at each event.

To get that I use

```
int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();

for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++)
{
            int id = event.getPointerId(i);
            int x = (int) event.getX(i);
            int y = (int) event.getY(i);
}
```

Now to save my x and y values I use two arrays and the above code is modified as given below

```
private int[] xval,yval; 

 for (int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++)
    {
            int id = event.getPointerId(i);
            int x = (int) event.getX(i);
            int y = (int) event.getY(i);
            xval[i] = x;
            yval[i] = y;

    }
```

The app crashes every time I try saving in an array. Is my approach wrong? Any help will be appreciated. I am new to android so excuse me if it is a silly doubt. I need to save in an array for few calculations used in my code. Nothing works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't allocated the array, so you are placing the values in unallocated memory.

Try:

```
int[] xval = new int[pointerCount];
```

Comment: Well yea :/ I forgot to.. I feel stupid! Thank you for the answer :)